# RSPEC test generate csv

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

```rb
def create_csv(some_hash)
  CSV.open("public/generated_file.csv", "wb") do |row|
    csv << ['Time', Time.now]
    some_hash.to_a.each { |data| row << data }
  end
end
```

How do I test that this method actually creates a file so I could check an output?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://relishapp.com/cucumber/aruba/v/0-11-0/docs/file/check-if-path-exists-and-is-file) is a link to the rspec docs. It uses `to_be_an_existing_file` to check for presence.

```rb
require 'spec_helper'

RSpec.describe 'Check if file exists and is file', :type => :aruba do
  let(:file) { 'public/generated_file.csv' }
  before { create_csv({...}) }
  after { FileUtils.rm_rf(Dir["#{Rails.root}/public/generated_file.csv"]) }

  it { expect(file).to be_an_existing_file }
end
```